# A good Linux based text editor, with FTP editing, and ability to keep alive ftp connection

Tags: linux, text, ubuntu, ftp, editor

I need a text editor for linux with the following features:

- Syntax Highlighting for PHP, Javascript (most have these)
- Autocompletion of braces, parenthesis, and

  Most important of all, editing via FTP.

  Even more important of all, have a 'keep alive' function when editing via ftp. I have a not so fast internet connection and many editors connect, save, and disconnect everytime i save the file.

The keep alive function that notepad++ has is a life saver. I've tried jEdit, but there isnt a keep alive feature.

Comment: What's wrong with Notepad++ for Wine? Works like a charm and is also integrated in Unity for instance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can achieve remote editing with **any** editor when using some Fuse based FTP-filesystem.

For example:
http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/

```
curlftpfs -o user=username:password ftp.example.com /my/mount/point
```

More preferably you should use SSH and SSHFS if possible.
http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html

For the editor I would recommend Geany or even Eclipse.

You should also checkout JetBrains' PHPStrom
http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/

Comment: hi there. Am trying out the curlftpfs. I've compiled the programe, but I can't seem to get the syntax right...

The ftp server I am trying to connect to is darkbrownandyellow.net

when i type "curlftpfs darkbrownandyellow.net ./dby" it gives an ftp permission denied error (exact message: Error connecting to ftp: Access denied: 530)- which is understandable as it hasnt asked me my password yet!

I tried running 'curlftpfs -h' to see the options but i have no idea where I can put in the password. There is no help on the sourceforge page.

Comment: @Vik username and password is an option for the -o switch. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: I tried Curlftpfs. It did the trick, but over slower connections, I found SSHFS to be the most stable.

Text editor that I have fallen in love with is Geany.

I mounted the sftp folder using sshfs. And edited the files as normal. Very very stable.

Comment: According to the following page on the Ubuntu forums (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSHFS):
Your ssh session will automatically log out if it is idle. To keep the connection active (alive) add this to ~/.ssh/config or to /etc/ssh/ssh_config on the client.


ServerAliveInterval 5


This will send a "keep alive" signal to the server every 5 seconds. You can usually increase this interval, and I use 120.

Answer (score 4):

Geany does everything but the remote connection, but that's what GVFS is for.

Comment: Or, if you prefer a KDE application: Kate using KIO.

Comment: I've done some reading, and GVFS is used when we use the 'connect to server' menu link from the places bar in Ubuntu.. yes?

Comment: That is correct. Connections made that way also show up under `~/.gvfs`.

Comment: I've tried the "Connect to server" method. Unfortunately, it doesn't keep alive the connection. Everytime I save, it reconnects, saves, and disconnects.

For fast internet connections, this would be just fine (I've used this method before), but for slower connections, connecting upon every save wastes almost 8-10 seconds.

Comment: I've been using Kate now for about a year. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 4):

**GVim/Vim** supports ftp & ssh/scp (read [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Edit_remote_files_locally_via_SCP/RCP/FTP) and [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_remote_files_via_scp_in_vim))

**Emacs** is seemed to support them also (read [here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AngeFtp))

General format is: protocol:user@host#port:dir/file

Comment: Brilliant remark about VIM.

Answer (score 3):

On Linux I've been using KDE's Kate for over a decade for editing remote text files. It can access and bookmark remote SFTP folders. It has syntax highlighting.

In fact I just installed Lubuntu on a laptop I intend to work on more and I came across this thread while looking for an alternative to Kate. I have used most of the alternatives described here and don't think any of them trumps kate when it comes to the ease with which it allows you to edit remote text files over sftp.

There are a couple of online js-based editors out there and a couple of chrome based ones worth checking out, but still after all this time Kate still rules my coding universe when using a linux desktop client.

Answer (score 2):

try eclipse. most awesome editor anyone has ever known. and i think editing via ftp is also possible.

can you just do a ping -t onto your ftp server? it will keep the connection alive.

ah and winscp actually can do this too. you just have to define your own editor to use.

Comment: I think it is sad that a slow bloated memory hogging java interpreted editor is our only choice for a real web development ide in linux... still.

Comment: True about the memory and the speed. Gets even worse with a lot of plugins. But the UI is nice.

Answer (score 2):

I think gedit fulfill most of your requirement. I do use gedit on my ubuntu machine.I first mount the drive from remote machine to my local machine and then use gedit to work with files.I never seen a problem of connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vim` to do that.

It has syntax highlighting for any language I know and you can set it up to auto-complete your parentheses.
You can edit files via ftp, and even use vim as an ftp navigator.
The [first google](http://www.marksanborn.net/software/modify-remote-files-with-vims-built-in-ftp-plugin/) hit, tells you how.

Answer (score 0):

Epeli's answer is the best answer so far, but it will only allow root to access the files. This is the way to allow all users to access the mount point:

```
sudo curlftpfs -o allow_other ftp://username:password@example.com /my/mount/point/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) v 8.5. Features:

- PHP (and many others) live syntax check and completion of parenthesis, etc
- FTP/SFTP/FTPS/SCP (I don't see SSH options, but I'm new to Komodo, maybe there's a way)
- You can use it as simple editor or with project manager
- There's a [paid IDE version of Komodo](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide/downloads) also, you can try it as well

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use **Sublime Text 2** in Linux. 

It supports code completion, code folding, snippets, themes, ftp, and a lot more and it faster then anything in Java as well as lighter on memory.

Comment: I use ST2 now as well. There's no substitute. It is the best. SFTP support is still a little slow though. The SFTP plugin by @wbond didn't cut it for me. I used SSHFS to mount the remote folder.

Answer (score 0):

I was also using Kate to do this until it inexplicably stopped working - now any file I open is blank, despite actually having data in.

However while Kate was working it was the perfect solution for this. Browsing around a remote ftp server was lightening fast. When I tried the same with curlftpfs it was incredibly slow to open files and folders.

Kate will also work on Windows thanks to the KDE Windows Initiative.